# Wrong calculation after using sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app to check prime numbers and display them. the user need to be able to save the number and load it upon restart of the app.

I have problem when retrieving the saved int from Sharedprefrences. the codes saves the int and loads it on the "loaddata" function. But when I start checking if the saved in is a primenumber, the code jumps 2 primenumbers. Eg if I save "11", the next primenumber should be "13" but it jumps to "19".

Would be great if someone could point into the right direction since i'm a bit of newbie.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button applyPrimeButton;
    private Button saveButton;
    private Button loadButton;

    public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";



int max = 500;
int j = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    applyPrimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply_prime_button);
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    loadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load_button);



    applyPrimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i = j; i <= max; i++) {
                if (isPrimeNumber(i)) {

                    textView.setText(i+"");
                    j = i+1;
                    break;

                }

            }
        }
    });



    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveData();
        }
    });
    loadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadData();

    }
    });


}




  public boolean isPrimeNumber(int nummer) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= nummer / 2; i++) {
            if (nummer % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }



public void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    int nummer = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("prime_save", nummer);
    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
   int nummer = sp.getInt("prime_save",0);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(nummer));



}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

1. You are not updating j to the correct value when loading data, and instead relying on what you are displaying in the textview.
2. To find prime number, it is enough to check until the square root of the original number and not half of it.

Try this:

```
applyPrimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
          if(j<max ){
            if (isPrimeNumber(j)) {
                textView.setText(j+"");
                j++;
            }
         }

    }
});


public void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("prime_save", j);
    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int nummer = sp.getInt("prime_save",0);
    j = nummer;
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(nummer));
}
```